# What exactly the reason of Import Error here?

Tags: python, django

**Hello Awesome People!**

A simple question about a thing that I came across and understand the issue but can't figure out why?

Not only I do not know for example whether `model1` must have the `ForeignKey` to `model2`, or `model2` with a `ManyToManyField` to `model1` (Confused).

Let's suppose we have **two(2) models files** and **three(3) class Model**, `app1.models.py` with [`Model1`, `ModelA`] and `app2.models.py` with [`Model2`].

**app1.models.py**

```
from app2.models import Model2

class Model1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(Model2)
```

**app2.models.py**

```
from app1.models import ModelA

 class Model2(models.Model):
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

This will definitely raise an error `ImportError`,

But if I do:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey("app2.Model2")
```

---

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    field2 = models.ForeignKey("app1.ModelA")
```

this will work well

Why exactly?

I Know that I can create the model in the file needed, but what I want is to understand why one works, and not the other.

Thank you!

Comment: Well Python interprets files linearly. You can see an import statement as a statement that asks Python to read the file you import into memory, but if your first file asks to import the second file, and the second file asks to import the first, then there is a cyclic problem.

Comment: Ok totally understand @WillemVanOnsem , and why use it that way work `ForeignKey("app2.Model2")` ? How Django bypass this cyclic problem as you said?

Comment: Well it first sees the reference as a *string*. Only after all applications are loaded, the "references" are made. By postponing the "linking" phase, we can thus first load all the classes into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import` statements are in fact **executable statements**. If you ask to `import foo.bar.qux`, then Python will first check if it has imported the file already (in `sys.modules`).

In case it has not yet imported that module, it will first perform a search what file corresponds to the module. In case the file can not be found, we get an `ImportError`, in the other case, Python will open the corresponding file, and "import it".

Importing means it will execute all the statements in the file (top to bottom). But now imagine that you have to files that require each other. In that case file `A` requires file `B` to be imported (completely). But `B` requires file `A` to be (completely) imported. There is no way to solve this: since there can be statements at the end of the file, that change the `class` definition, etc. But we have reached an `import` statement, which is a "contract" that the module is entirely loaded. So this is basically the "*chicken-and-the-egg*"-problem.

We can however solve such cyclic imports by **postponing the linking**. Instead of passing a *reference* to the class. We can for example pass some sort of token (Django uses strings, but there could have been different ways). Now the string does not introduces a problem, since before we start interpreting, the "builtin library" of Python is already loaded into memory.

After all the model classes are loaded into memory, Django will perform a "*linking*" phase. After the loading phase, all the `models.py` files are loaded into memory, so now we can replace the strings with references to the classes. So Django basically solves the problem by postponing linking the `ForeignKey`s to the real class object.

Comment: that's clear and explicit, I want to ask you if you think the fact that I use (even abuse) the reference of string  in different files can raise this error `ValueError: Related model 'index.model2' cannot be resolved` I use celery and when I try to display the queryset of a Model (this model has a `ForeignKey('index.model2')`) i got the error, I think Celery may be use the string reference of django as  absolute import. Thank you very much!

Comment: @EuChi: well in case you would use for example `'app.Foo'` and that model does not exists (or it is not a model class), Django will indeed produce an error, something like: `otherapp.SomeModel.some_field: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'app.Foo', which is either not installed, or is abstract.`. So Django will probably fail to start, and points out what field refers to a non-existing (or abstract) `Model`.

Comment: If the model doesn't exist an error with `lazy reference` will raise, but in my case, the Model actually exists.

Comment: @EuChi: does the `index` application is registered as an `INSTALLED_APP` in the `settings.py` file?

Comment: yeah everything is ok, when I do this in templates or with a print(), I got all my records. the problem is when I try to send email with celery to a user about all the records, I just send a queryset to the template with get_template().render(cotext), when I remove the Foreign Field with `defer()` it works, put it back `Related model 'index.model2'` error raises.

Answer (score 1):

The notation

```
field1 = models.ForeignKey(Model2)
```

implies that "Model2" has already been created. But python create the two objects in a sequence. You get this error when python creates ModelA, which try to point on ModelB, which is not existing yet.
You can solve this issue by using

```
field1 = models.ForeignKey("app2.Model2")
```

You can also see this in the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself.

Comment: I totally aware that I can fix the issue by using the string reference `"app2.Model2"`, My question is why?

Comment: As I wrote - Because at least one model you are referencing to, does not exist yet. This is because python create the models in sequence